# Using a function from another class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I'm just starting with OOP (shame on me), so be gentle with me.

I have an ErrorHandler class that calls a function from my main Application class to include an error page.
So I'm using `Application::status_page( $type );` in a function in the ErrorHandler class.

This is how the status_page function looks like (it's a function to include all kinds of custom messages):

```
public function status_page( $page )
{
    // Include the status page that has been set in the routes
    include( STATUS_PAGE_DIR . $this->status_pages[$page] . '.html' );
}
```

I'm now getting an `Undefined property: ErrorHandler::$status_pages` which makes total sence to me. But what is the best way to solve this? Maybe let the ErrorHandler class extend the main Application class?

I hope I was clear and thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: might consider composition over inheritance,btw did ur ErrorHandler class have $status_page property?

Comment: Yes $status_pages has been set. So you mean I just initiate all my other classes like ErrorHandler in the construct of my main Application Class? So I don't have to use static functions, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$status_pages must be defined in the header of the class

also, you must declare the function as

```
public static function status_page($page)
```

if you want to use it like that.

Comment: If you dont' want to to use it static, you'll have to create an instance of the class with $var = new ClassName();

Comment: When I make it static I get the error "Using $this when not in object context". Creating a new instance is not an option I'm afraid (it will reset $status_pages).